# On dom ready, get all data-src from <img>'s and set them in the src attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, asynchronous, attr

In a page I have this:

```
<figure><img src="" data-src="img1.png"></figure>
<figure><img src="" data-src="img2.png"></figure>
<figure><img src="" data-src="img3.png"></figure>
<figure><img src="" data-src="img4.png"></figure>
```

and goes on.

I am trying to make an async load without using a jquery plugin and make it as simple as possible.

So I thought, when the dom is ready and the page is fully loaded, set the data-src to the src.

If I do this: `console.log($('figure img').attr('data-src'))` I get only the first image. so it gives me result: `img1.png`

So how can I say, **when dom ready all the figure > img > data-src to be set as src for that img.**

So from this:

```
<figure><img src="" data-src="img1.png"></figure>
<figure><img src="" data-src="img2.png"></figure>
<figure><img src="" data-src="img3.png"></figure>
<figure><img src="" data-src="img4.png"></figure>
```

to this:

```
<figure><img src="img1.png"></figure>
<figure><img src="img2.png"></figure>
<figure><img src="img3.png"></figure>
<figure><img src="img4.png"></figure>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since version 1.4.3 or so, jQuery has understood "data-" attributes directly.  So just do this:

```
$('figure img').each(function() {
  this.src = $(this).data('src');
});
```

You have to use `.each()` in order to separate out the processing of each element in the initially-selected list so that the operation you perform can use that element by itself.

Comment: @Phrogz, Pointy: Using `.data()` is neat, and great if you need to work with the data later on, but if not, it's faster to use `.attr()`, and doesn't create an unnecessary permanent reference to the data.

Comment: ...but `this.src` is definitely better, so +1.

Comment: @amnotiam re: using .data() - I had not thought of that; it's a very good point. This is one of those situations wherein I'm not really sure I understand why one would find oneself with the problem in the first place ...

Comment: @Pointy: Yeah, the `data-` attribute seems most useful for sending a simple string from the server with the element. `jQuery.cache` is great for more complex data, but for simple strings, I'd rather just look at the attribute. Ultimately we'll be doing `this.dataset.src` once the compatibility gets there.

Answer (score 6):

```
$('figure > img').prop('src',function() {
    return $(this).attr('data-src');
});
```

---

Or a little quicker with `getAttribute()`.

```
$('figure > img').prop('src',function() {
    return this.getAttribute('data-src');
});
```

---

If you really want to remove the `data-src`, then chain `.removeAttr('data-src')` to the end.

```
$('figure > img').prop('src',function() {
    return this.getAttribute('data-src');
}).removeAttr('data-src');
```

Comment: I'm slapping my forehead **so hard** right now for not having absorbed the fact that this works.

Comment: @Pointy: You mean the function argument? :)

Comment: @Phrogz: I'll bet that using @Pointy's `this.src` will be faster. I'd probably do that if it was me since `src` doesn't really need any jQuery fixes. But between `.attr()` and `.data()`, I did some testing last week, and `.attr()` came out on top.

Comment: ...fastest would certainly be in favor of old-school `this.src = this.getAttribute('data-src')`

Comment: @Phrogz: [Found the jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/attr-vs-data). I tipped the scales in favor of `.data()` by pre-populating the `jQuery.cache` before the tests run, but `.attr()` still came out on top.

Comment: I find both answers pretty similar and I liked both too. Although getAttribute seems to be faster than data whatsoever, but in my case for 2-3 images, speed isnt priority. Because of @Pointy answering first I choosed his answer. Thank you

Comment: @Jonathan: Sure thing. Pointy's answer is a good one, and you're right, with just a few images, it just won't make a difference.